# Is the website mercurial-scm.org no longer in use?

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to download the hg client, but the site `mercurial-scm.org` is dead. and has been so for a week. did they move? I can't find any news on this, or any chatter on the web. I thought it was just my connection, but according to uptime tracking sites, it's been down for quite some time.

Comment: https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/mercurial-scm.org

Answer (score 2):

I was able to download the HG 5.71 installer just now from https://mercurial-scm.org. Either the problem is resolved or it was on your end.

The TortoiseHG website is also a good source of Mercurial, even if you don't want to use TortoiseHG itself, since it comes with HG bundled.

https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/index.html